# Connecting several screens to Dell laptop

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, dell-precision

Is it possible to connect several screens to my Dell Precision laptop M4600? It only has one VGA and HDMI outlet?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to connect two monitors. Typically VGA and digital connections such as DVI/HDMI/DP are not shared between each other. If it doesn't let you, it may be a hardware limitation, not being able to drive that many monitors. If this is a recent model, it should be able to drive both new monitors.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok not doing a lot of graphics processing on the external monitor, and just need it to keep browsers and office documents open, for example, then you can add any number of USB-to-DVI adapters. I've had excellent luck with the [See2 Extreme](http://www.eclipsetouch.com/uv250.htm#img/uv250/uv250_1.jpg).